# lo que quiero lograr hacer es que cuando ingreses la letra E o la T diferentes cosas dependiendo lo que ingrese el usuario

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Lo que quería decir es que el texto me pide que

cout<<"Ingrese un modo de pago E es efectivo o debito y T es tarjeta de credito: ";

Cuando ingreses la E tengas un 10% de descuento o la T que tenga un 15% de intereses, dependiendo lo ingresado en la variante numero

La pregunta sería que quiero lograr hacer es que cuando ingreses la letra E o T hagan cosas diferentes pero no se como hacerlo adecuadamente

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numero, can_pro_ven, total_ven;
    can_pro_ven<=100;
    char pagoE[] = {'E'};
    char pagoT[] = {'T'};

    cout<< "ingrece la venta";
    cin>> numero;
    while (numero!=0)
    {


    cout<< "ingrece la venta";
        cin >> numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de productos vendidos: ";
        cin>>can_pro_ven;

    cout<<"Ingrese el total de ventas: ";
        cin>>total_ven;

    cout<<"Ingrese un modo de pago E es efectivo o devito y T es targeta de credito: ";
        cin>>pagoE;
        cin>>pagoT;

    if ('E')
    {printf("HOLA");}
    else
    {printf("hola");}

    if ('T')
    {printf("CHAU");}
    else
    {printf("chau");}


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿A caso esta pregunta no es la misma que [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/507756/169744)?

Comment: En un comentario de [la otra pregunta](/q/507756) te han dicho qué hacer dependiendo del caso. ¿Qué problema estás teniendo?

Comment: perdón muchas gracias por responderme, es que no había visto el cartelito de mostrar otros 2 mensajes pensé que se mostraría automáticamente

Comment: Tienes la idea correcta, tienes que usar `if`. Pero al ver la forma en la que lo implementas, creo que la mejor respuesta que te puedo dar es que regreses ya sea al material de clase o a la serie de tutoriales que estes siguiendo, y repases los fundamentos. No solo copies y pegues en tu editor, entiendelos. No suelo responder este tipo de preguntas ya que considero que dar una respuesta no es de mucha ayuda si no tienes los fundamentos bien cimentados.

Comment: Pero si luego de repasar tu material aun no logras hacerlo, dejame un comentario con un `@Pablochaches` al final. Al menos estare seguro de que tendras lo necesario para que la respuesta te sea util.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay algunos detalles con tu código, creo que debes revisar el material que has utilizado para aprender como dice el comentario de tu pregunta

`can_pro_ven<=100` el operador `<=`significa menor o igual y sirve para hacer comparaciones el resultado será `true` (1) si el valor de la variable es menor o igual a 100 o `false` (0) en caso contrario. A fines prácticos, esta línea de código en tu programa no hace nada porque no estás asignando el resultado de la operación a ninguna variable

Al solicitar tipo de pago estas usando 2 veces `cin` por lo que el usuario tendría que ingresar 2 formas de pago pero en realidad tu necesitas una sola variable por lo que podrías utilizar `cin>>pago;`

La razón por la que tus `if` no funcionan es porque no estas comparando nada

`if('E')` por sí solo va a devolver siempre `true` (1) al igual que `if('T')` te hace falta comparar esos caracteres con algo. Puedes compararlos directamente con la variable pago y quedaría de esta forma

`if(pago == 'E')`

De esta forma si el usuario ingresa 'E' en el tipo de pago entonces esta condición se cumplirá.

Las condiciones que tienes son excluyentes, es decir, o el tipo de pago es en efectivo 'E' o es con tarjeta 'T', por lo que debes utilizar `if` anidados o relacionados

```
if (pago == 'E') {
    printf("Efectivo");
}
else if (pago == 'T'){
    printf("Tarjeta");
}
```

Podrías leer el código anterior de la siguiente forma "Si pago es igual a 'E' entonces imprime 'Efectivo' en caso contrario, si pago es igual a 'T' entonces imprime 'Tarjeta' (Tarjeta va con J)

Podrías incluso poner una condición más en caso de que el usuario ingrese un caracter diferente a 'E' o 'T'

```
if (pago == 'E') {
    printf("Efectivo");
}
else if (pago == 'T'){
    printf("Targeta");
}
else {
    printf("Método de pago no válido");
}
```

Una cosa más, al inicio definiste dos variables tipo char `pagoE` y `pagoT` que  los inicializaste con 'E' y 'T' respectivamente. Si deseas utilizar esas variables podrías hacerlo de esta forma (Edición, me faltó poner el índice del arreglo por que no se puede comparar arreglo con char)

```
if (pago == pagoE[0]) {
    printf("Efectivo");
}
else if (pago == pagoT[0]){
    printf("Targeta");
}
else {
    printf("Método de pago no válido");
}
```

Si deseas hacer la comparación sin utilizar tus variables `pagoE` y `pagoT` lo recomendable sería quitarlas. Evita declarar variables que no vas a utilizar

Espero que te sea de utilidad, hay otras cosas en tu código que podrían mejorarse pero eso se puede aprender más adelante, por el momento con que entiendas como funcionan los `if` (Que es tu pregunta original) es suficiente

Éxito

Comment: `pagoE`  y `pagoT` son arrays, mientras que `pago` es un `char`. No se pueden comparar esos tipos entre sí directamente.

Comment: Ah, se me pasó poner el índice del arreglo, ya edité la respuesta

Comment: quizás sería más sencillo y lógico cambiar los tipos de `pagoE` y `pagoT` a `char` ... o usar `std::string`, que por algo está puesta la etiqueta de C++

Comment: Así es, el código tiene varios detalles pero no están relacionados a la pregunta, el problema que el usuario tiene es con los IF

Answer (score 0):

**No mezcles I/O de C y C++**

Lo primero: procura no mezclar mecanismos de entrada/salida propios de C (`printf`, `scanf`) con los propios de C++ (`cout`, `cin`). La razón es que cada mecanismo tiene su propia forma de hacer las cosas.

Si en tu ejemplo funciona es porque alguien pensó que sería buena idea activar por defecto la sincronización entre ambos mecanismos. Esta sincronización es una de las razones por las que, por defecto, interacción con la consola es tan lenta en C++. Sin embargo, esta sincronización puede deshabilitarse en cualquier momento y, si esto sucede, tu programa (o tu parte de un proyecto más grande) podría empezar a comportarse de forma errática.

Para desactivar la sincronización basta con ejecutar la siguiente línea de código:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

Una vez ejecutada esta línea, La I/O propia de C++ (`cout`, `cin`) será bastante más rápida que la homóloga heredada de C (`printf`, `scanf`).

**Ordenar ideas**

En tu código hay una mezcla de diferentes enfoques y acercamientos al problema. El resultado es un código que dificilmente te va a funcionar.

Para empezar, las variables `pagoE` y `pagoT` no son necesarias. Para gestionar el tipo de pago solo necesitas una única variable. La razón es que tu, en principio, no sabes si el usuario va a elegir un método de pago u otro. Es justamente lo que le estás preguntando al usuario. Lo que tienes que hacer es pedirle al usuario que introduzca el método de pago (almacenas un valor en una variable) y luego tu verificas cual es el tipo de pago introducido (evalúas esa variable).

Dicho con un ejemplo:

```
int numero;

// Fase 1: Se almacena la opcion del usuario en una variable
std::cout << "Introduce un número par o impar: ";
std::cin << numero;

// Fase 2: Se evalua el contenido de la variable
if (numero % 2 == 0)
    std::cout << "Has introducido un número par";
else:
    std::cout << "Has introducido un número impar";
```

A partir de este punto asumiré que `pagoE` se ha renombrado a `pago` y que se ha eliminado la variable `pagoC`:

```
char pago[] = {'E'};
```

**Inicialización de arrays**

```
char pago[] = {'E'};
```

Tanto en C como en C++, las cadenas de caracteres deben terminar con el caracter nulo `\0`. De no ser así no podrás usar las funciones que permiten gestionar y manipular cadenas de caracteres.

En tu caso estás inicializando un array de tipo `char` con un único elemento (el caracter `'E'`. Esto quiere decir que tu array de caracteres no puede ser tratado como una cadena de caracteres ya que carece del finalizador de cadena.

De la misma forma, tampoco podrías usar ese array para almacenar cadenas de caracteres ya que para ello necesitarías poder añadir, al menos, dos elementos (un caracter y el terminador de la cadena) y tu solo admites uno.

Aquí tienes dos posibles soluciones:

- Usas cadenas de caracteres
- Usas caracteres

Para usar cadenas de caracteres basta con emplear comillas dobles en vez de comillas simples:

```
char pago[] = "E";
```

Aunque, por otro lado, estás programando en C++, así que sería más cómodo para ti usar `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

string pago = "E";
```

Si, en cambio, prefieres el uso de caracteres, adelante:

```
char pago = 'E';
```

Todo esto sería si necesitases inicialiar la cadena de caracteres, pero es algo que no necesitas. El valor de `pago` debe darlo el usuario, no tu.

Por comodidad, yo te recomiendo usar `std::string`:

```
std::string pago;
```

Ahora, ya puedes dejar que el usuario introduzca el método de pago. Una vez superado ese trámite es hora de aplicar los descuentos/incrementos correspondientes.

Llegados a este punto, no entiendo todos esos valores que le pides al usuario:

- venta -> numero
- cantidad de productos - can_pro_ven
- total ventas -> total_ven

Tu solo necesitas saber cuántas unidades se venden y el precio de cada una de ellas. El resto lo puedes calcular tu mismo (total = unidades * precio).

Por cierto, nota, que el tipo `int` no admite decimales. Si tienes que aplicar descuentos/recargos que implique generar decimales, o usas tipos con decimales `float` o `double` o el programa te arrojará resultados incorrectos

El código final podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int unidades;
    std::cout << "Numero de articulos: ";
    std::cin >> unidades;

    float precio;
    std::cout << "precio unitario: ";
    std::cin >> precio;

    std::string tipo_pago;
    std::cout << "Tipo de pago (E) efectivo o (C) credito: ";
    std::cin >> tipo_pago;

    float total;
    if (tipo_pago == "E")
    {
        // Aplicas el descuento del 10%
    }
    else if (tipo_pago == "C")
    {
        // Aplicas recargo del 15%
    }
    else
    {
        // metodo de pago no valido
    }

    std::cout << "Total a pagar: " << total << '\n';
}
```